# Overwriting existing ios native app with xamarin app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an app that was built in native ios

We are developing a new app on xamarin

My problem the users are all over the place and due to my predecessors bad management the ipads are locked with no mdm. And the apps are whitelisted

If i give the new app the same bundle ID etc will it overwrite the old native ID?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, if the bundle id is the same it should overwrite the old app

Comment: He also needs to use the same signing key.

Comment: Great, puts my mind at rest, im thinking im going to ask them to make a quick hello world app to test the theory just in case but, you have put my mind at ease

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

> A bundle ID or bundle identifier uniquely identifies an application in
> Apple's ecosystem. This means that no two applications can have the
> same bundle identifier.

If you name the new app with the same bundle id with the old one, it will overwrite the old app.

Refer: [bundle_ids](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/bundle_ids)

[what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers](https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers/).